# IIS Url Redirect remove repeated character from URL

Tags: redirect

Currently I have a set of articles located under the /articles directory.

The article name in the url is being managed by a CMS such that if the character is not on a letter or number (a-z, 0-9), it will replace the character with a '-'.

For example:
"M.K. Jacobs" -> /articles/m-k--Jacobs

The...Start, of Jacob's life -> /articles/the---start--of-jacob-s-life

I now need to redirect to a new url. The idea is that when a user types the old url, it will be redirected to the new one. The new one has the same structure except that every '--' or '---' is only '-'

"M.K. Jacobs" -> /articles/m-k-jacobs

The...Start, of Jacob's life -> /articles/the-start-of-jacob-s-life

Is there a url rule for replacing every appearance '--' or '---' for a single '-'?

Answer (score 0):

After trying with some Url Rewrite rules, I decided to do it on the Global.asax file

```
public void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   string url = Request.RawUrl.ToLower();
   if (myRegex.IsMatch(url))
   {
     url = url.Replace("---", "-").Replace("--", "-");
     Response.Redirect(url);
   }
}
```